# Disconnect external accessory without physically disconnecting

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, external-accessory

My app communicates with an external device via EA Framework.  I would like to do a "soft disconnect", i.e. a software disconnect without actually physically disconnecting the device.  The only way I see for a soft disconnect is to close the EASession's inputStream and outputStream.  Question: Will the external device know I have closed the streams so it doesn't attempt to communicate further? Is there another way to do soft disconnect?

Answer (score 2):

i think that actually is impossible to do a real soft disconnection.
i say 'think' cause you never stop learning on EA Framework (One week ago i found the showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter for example, maybe is useful for you for inApp-connection).

I use a EASession(s) manager to easily switch between connections. so forgot the word 'disconnection' and replace it with 'switch' :D

If you need disconnection, implements some function on btdevice-side and execute this to disconnect as soon as you receive a command from the iPhone.